# rtmpdump check status by command line

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rtmp

I tried doing rtmpdump -r "rtmp-raw=rtmpe://watch.playfooty.tv/live playpath=nba1569 swfUrl=http://www.playfooty.tv/play/player/player.swf live=1 pageUrl=http://www.playfooty.tv/"
But the output it´s like offline always

```
RTMPDump v2.2e
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
DEBUG: Parsing...
WARNING: Unknown protocol!

DEBUG: Parsed host : watch.playfooty.tv
DEBUG: Parsed app : live playpath=nba1569 swfUrl=http:/
DEBUG: Protocol : RTMP
DEBUG: Hostname : watch.playfooty.tv
DEBUG: Port : 1935
DEBUG: Playpath : www.playfooty.tv/play/player/player.swf live=1 pageUrl=http://www.playfooty.tv/
DEBUG: tcUrl : rtmp://watch.playfooty.tv:1935/live playpath=nba1569 swfUrl=http:/
DEBUG: app : live playpath=nba1569 swfUrl=http:/
DEBUG: live : no
DEBUG: timeout : 30 sec
```

I tried a lot of links of a list and seems offline with this command, but When I play it in a software it worked.

Does anyone have an idea how to test if this kind of links are alive or die?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
rtmpdump -i "rtmpe://watch.playfooty.tv/live playpath=nba1569 swfUrl=http://www.playfooty.tv/play/player/player.swf live=1 pageUrl=http://www.playfooty.tv/"
```

Admittedly the online documentation on RtmpDump is pretty poor, however it is
listed in the command line help

```
--url|-i url   URL with options included
               (e.g. rtmp://host[:port]/path swfUrl=url tcUrl=url)
```

http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/rtmpdump/2012-July/002016.html

Comment: I have compiled 2.3 version too and the output is : invalid option -- 'i' unknown option: ?. In the help is where I found the -r but without luck. Thanks Steven for your reply.

Comment: You need to compile from git master

Comment: Hi steven, I have done and checked the command, it works very good thanks :), but my prob is, I ´m doing that with php with popen, Is there other command or a way to stop or limit the rtmpdump -i to some seconds?, to catch the output using preg_match and decide if it´s online or not?

Comment: I tried but it does not stop :(, If I understand correctly it stop the stream based seconds, But I don´t know the current time of the stream to make a sum up that secs and then stop. Thanks for your reply Steven